# Should Two Unrelated Remarks Be Presented in One "Remark" Section, or Two?

Tags: article-writing

Suppose at a certain point in my article I would like to make what are essentially two unrelated observations, where each pertains to the topic of discussion but neither is of sufficient importance to warrant inclusion in the main text.  I could opt to have two remark sections, one immediately following the other with no intervening main text; alternatively, I could have only one remark section, with both remarks being placed there.

Which is considered better form?

Answer (score 3):

I think it's clearly better to have two remarks if they're unrelated; you want to be able to refer to them separately (e.g. "oh, see remark 2.4.2" vs. "oh, see remark 2.4.3").